# Import error while importing tensorflow,keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I installed tensorflow 1.8. When `import keras`or `import tensorflow`.Iam getting

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-dc6fd3b71e3e> in <module>
----> 1 from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
      2 from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
      3 from keras.models import Sequential
      4 from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, LSTM, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Dropout, Activation
      5 from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py in <module>
      4 from . import data_utils
      5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
      7 
      8 # Globally-importable utils.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py in <module>
      7 from six.moves import range
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from .. import backend as K
     10 
     11 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in <module>
     87 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     88     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 89     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     90 else:
     91     # Try and load external backend.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in <module>
      3 from __future__ import print_function
      4 
----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops as tf_ops
      7 from tensorflow.python.training import moving_averages

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     25 
     26 try:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     57 
     58 # Protocol buffers
---> 59 from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
     60 from tensorflow.core.framework.node_def_pb2 import *
     61 from tensorflow.core.framework.summary_pb2 import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py in <module>
      4 import sys
      5 _b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
----> 6 from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
      7 from google.protobuf import message as _message
      8 from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py in <module>
     45   import binascii
     46   import os
---> 47   from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
     48   _USE_C_DESCRIPTORS = getattr(_message, '_USE_C_DESCRIPTORS', False)
     49 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Please someone help me with this.

Comment: Can you post your setup and environment? e.g. which packages are installed and the versions of os, python you are using?